# What is File History in Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8

In Control Panel of my Windows 8 I saw File History. To know about it I just ran it once and I did it on my pen drive. What is it actually ? What is it used for ? Is it like System Backup ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 8's File History used to be called Previous Versions in Vista and 7, but it's been revamped with a much easier-to-use, more backup-focused interface. File History doesn't back up your whole system. Instead, it only backs up the files in your Libraries—essentially, your personal documents, files, and media. You can add any folders you want to a library, of course, but it won't back up your entire computer the way Windows 7 File Recovery does. Also, instead of running large backups every week or month, it takes a snapshot of your files every hour, so you can restore your files in a much more fine-grained fashion.

If you accidentally delete a file and need to restore it—or if you change a file and decide you want the old version back—you can restore that file very simply. Open up Windows Explorer and head to the folder where that file used to reside, You an then click the "Home" button and click the File History icon on the right side of the Ribbon. Alternatively, you can head back to Control Panel > File History and click "Restore Personal Files" on the left sidebar.

Comment: So can I use File History to recover my files ?

Comment: Yes, but only those which are part of the "Libraries".

Comment: @edvinas.me - thats not exactly true.  Its actually as simple as only files which Windows kept track of.  If Windows never kept track of the file, then it wouldn't have stored any information about the file, thus making recovery of said file not possible.

Comment: I do mention this in the first part when saying that it only tracks your library files.